# What does hard mode do in Unidentified Falling Objects?

Tags: unidentified-falling-objects

The shop in Unidentified Falling Options has a bonus marked with a skull icon and the description "hard mode with 1.2x score multiplier". What changes in hard mode?

[image: Shop with hard mode bonus]